# extend dataframe with nonexistent dates

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe containing irregular time events. I would like to extend it by adding additional rows (empty at first, to be filled later) for every week which is not yet there. This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id' : [1,1,2,2,2],
               'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-02-01', '2019-01-01', '2019-03-01', '2019-05-01'],
               'value': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]})
df["week"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"]).dt.to_period('W')


all_weeks = pd.period_range(min(df["date"]), max(df["date"]), freq='W')

all_weeks
PeriodIndex(['2018-12-31/2019-01-06', '2019-01-07/2019-01-13',
         '2019-01-14/2019-01-20', '2019-01-21/2019-01-27',
         '2019-01-28/2019-02-03', '2019-02-04/2019-02-10',
         '2019-02-11/2019-02-17', '2019-02-18/2019-02-24',
         '2019-02-25/2019-03-03', '2019-03-04/2019-03-10',
         '2019-03-11/2019-03-17', '2019-03-18/2019-03-24',
         '2019-03-25/2019-03-31', '2019-04-01/2019-04-07',
         '2019-04-08/2019-04-14', '2019-04-15/2019-04-21',
         '2019-04-22/2019-04-28', '2019-04-29/2019-05-05'],
        dtype='period[W-SUN]', freq='W-SUN')
```

My data cover 18 weeks, therefore I'd like to have `df` extended such that it has 18*2 = 36 rows, with empty `values` for the newly added rows, but with both `id`s appearing 18 times. How can I achieve that?

*Expected Output*:

```
id    week                     value
1.0   '2018-12-31/2019-01-06'  100
1.0   '2019-01-07/2019-01-13'  NaN
...
1.0   '2019-04-29/2019-05-05'  NaN
2.0   '2018-12-31/2019-01-06'  300
2.0   '2019-01-07/2019-01-13'  NaN
...
```

I assume it's an outer merge along the `week` column, but I haven't figured out his yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit 2019-10-20**

Custom function to apply per `id` group:

```
 def period_index(df, num_weeks=36):
   weeks = pd.period_range(min(df["date"]), 
                               periods=num_weeks, 
                               freq='W', 
                               name='week')
   return df.reindex(weeks).drop('id', axis=1)
```

Set index in `df`:

```
df.set_index('week', inplace=True)
```

Groupby `id` and apply our func, clean up columns and index:

```
df.groupby('id').apply(period_index).reset_index().drop('date', axis=1)
```

Sample of output:

```
    id                   week  value
0    1  2018-12-31/2019-01-06  100.0
1    1  2019-01-07/2019-01-13    NaN
2    1  2019-01-14/2019-01-20    NaN
3    1  2019-01-21/2019-01-27    NaN
4    1  2019-01-28/2019-02-03  200.0
5    1  2019-02-04/2019-02-10    NaN
6    1  2019-02-11/2019-02-17    NaN
7    1  2019-02-18/2019-02-24    NaN
8    1  2019-02-25/2019-03-03    NaN
9    1  2019-03-04/2019-03-10    NaN
....
62   2  2019-07-01/2019-07-07    NaN
63   2  2019-07-08/2019-07-14    NaN
64   2  2019-07-15/2019-07-21    NaN
65   2  2019-07-22/2019-07-28    NaN
66   2  2019-07-29/2019-08-04    NaN
67   2  2019-08-05/2019-08-11    NaN
68   2  2019-08-12/2019-08-18    NaN
69   2  2019-08-19/2019-08-25    NaN
70   2  2019-08-26/2019-09-01    NaN
71   2  2019-09-02/2019-09-08    NaN
```

Comment: thanks. Maybe I was a bit unclear, but I need basically the full combination of `id`and `week` in thre resulting dataset. In your example, `id`is not set for the new rows.

Comment: What's the logic for setting the `id`?

Comment: None that matters here. I just want to have a row for every `id` for every week, so I can fill the values in between.

Comment: What should the five rows of `NaN`s be in the answer I posted?

Comment: I added expected output

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution:

```
from itertools import product
all_weeks = pd.period_range(df["date"].min(), df["date"].max(), freq='W')
all_snrs = df["id"].unique()
all_rows = pd.DataFrame(product(all_weeks, all_snrs), columns=["week", "id"])
output = pd.merge(all_rows, df, how='outer').sort_values(by=["id", "week"])
```